# Does the sentence "All closed, unbounded convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals $[a, +\infty)$ and $(-\infty, b]$" hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Again arguing my calculus's classmate, we focused on this sentence.

"All closed, unbounded convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the interval in the form $[a, +\infty)$ and $(-\infty, b]$, with $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$."

About me the sentence holds true, since $[a, +\infty)$ and $(-\infty, b]$ are trivially unbounded and convex. They are also closed since the complemetar is open (my classmate disagree my last thought).

Could someone please tell me if my reasoning holds true or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The wording of your statement is weird. Try using Google Translate to translate your questions.

Comment: I don't think it's actually a _sentence_. "All and only one..." makes little sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb R$ is also closed, convex and unbounded, but is not of the forms you are considering. Other than that, you are right.

Here's a sketch of the proof.

Let $X$ be an an unbounded closed convex subset of $\Bbb R$. Consider $a=\inf X$ and $b=\sup X$. If $a=-\infty$ and $b=+\infty$, use convexity to prove that $X=\Bbb R$.

If $a\in \Bbb R$ and $b=+\infty$, use convexity to prove $X=(a,+\infty)$ or $X=[a,+\infty)$, and of course, discard the first one since it's not closed.

Do the same for the case $a=-\infty$ and $b\in \Bbb R$.

The case $a,b\in \Bbb R$ can't happen since $X$ is unbounded.

Comment: So, excluding the whole $\mathbb{R}$, are they?

Comment: Yes, other than $\Bbb R$, those are all the closed unbounded convex subsets of $\Bbb R$

Comment: When listing all the closed unbounded convex subsets, why not make a list of three types, rather than adding "other than $\mathbb R$" to the problem?  Like this:$$(-\infty, a],\quad [a,\infty),\quad (-\infty,+\infty),\qquad \text{where }a \in \mathbb R$$